# Whistling sound under the engine

Tags: noise

I have this weird sound coming from below my Golf GTI engine.
When I start the car in the morning, nothing happens. The car is perfect and silent. After about 10 mins drive, small whistling sound is heard from the engine area. As I drive the car more, sound gets louder and louder.
The strange thing is, when I accelerate to a speed higher than 40km/hr the sound stops. As soon as I stop acceleration (even when the car is moving forward without pressing the petrol pedal) , the sound starts again and it never stops until i press acceleration pedal.
What could be the problem?

Comment: It sounds to me as though this is a vacuum leak of some sort.  Generally the intake manifold vacuum is highest when the load on the engine is low and the vacuum is lowest when the throttle plate is open.  You should be able to hear such a leak with the engine at idle and the hood open.  If you have trouble pinpointing it, try a stethoscope-type device to help find it.